# Send a post request after an update

Tags: trigger, api, update, post

I'm trying to send a post request after an update from a record, and then is going to generate a link for the post request, I had the idea to create the post request after an insert using a trigger but now I need to do it after an update, can someone help me or explain to me how to complete this task?

Code for the class that I'm using to send the POST request and also create the URL for the custom field:

```apex
public class myclass {
    public static void issueCU(List<Internal_Request__c> triggerNew){
        List<Id> irIds = new List<Id>();
        for(Internal_Request__c irs : triggerNew){
            irIds.add(irs.Id);
        }
        createTicket(irIds);
    }    
        
    @future(callout = true)
    public static void createTicket(List<Id> irsID){
        List<Internal_Request__c> updateRecord = new List<Internal_Request__c>();
        List<Internal_Request__c> workRecord = [SELECT Id, jira_key__c,Subject__c,Description__c,Jira_Type__c, URL_Jira__c FROM Internal_Request__c WHERE ID IN :irsID];
        for(Internal_Request__c irst :workRecord){
            Jira_credential__mdt globalmc = Jira_credential__mdt.getInstance('Admin');
            string username = globalmc.Username__c;
            string password = globalmc.Password__c; // is the security token from Atlassian account profile --> Manage your Account-->Security-->API token-->Create and manage API tokens--> Manage your account-->API tokens
            String auth_header = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password));
            String url = globalmc.Jira_URL__c;
            
            Http http = new Http();
            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');
            req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
            req.setHeader('Authorization', auth_header);
            req.setHeader('X-Atlassian-Token', 'nocheck');
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setEndpoint(url);
            req.setBody('{ "fields": { "project": { "key": "'+irst.Jira_Key__c+'" }, "summary": "'+irst.Subject__c+'", "issuetype": { "name": "'+irst.Jira_Type__c+'" },  "description": "'+irst.Description__c+'" } }');  
            try {
                HttpResponse res = http.send(req); 
                system.debug(res);
                Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
                String jira_key = (String) m.get('key');
                string link = 'https://mycustomurl.com/browse/'+jira_key+'';   
                irst.URL_Jira__c = link;
                irst.Key__c= jira_key;
                system.debug(link);
                updateRecord.add(irst);
                system.debug(irst);
                system.debug(req);
                update updateRecord;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                system.debug('Error: ' + e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code for the trigger:

```apex
trigger CUD_Jira on Internal_Request__c (after insert) {
    if (trigger.isInsert) {
        jira_Insert.issueCU(Trigger.New);
    }
}
```

Comment: to answer this - one would need to know under what circumstances the ticket should be created after an update. Like - on every update? only when certain conditions are satisfied?

Comment: the ticket needs to be created when they update the record from a new action that will be placed in the page layout and will be only one time @cropredy

Comment: Since you are storing the link to the JIRA ticket in URL_Jira__c, you can filter out the record which is already linked to a JIRA ticket.